# Will poll return -1 if any POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL revents are set?

Tags: c, posix

From a poll man page:

> The bits returned in revents can include any of those specified in
>   events, or one of the values POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL

Return Value:

> On success, a positive number is returned; this is the number of structures which have nonzero revents fields (in other words, those descriptors with events or errors reported). A value of 0 indicates that the call timed out and no file descriptors were ready. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

**If poll sets one of POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL in revents, does this mean that the poll function will return -1? If not, when will poll return -1?**

My guess is no, since the first sentence in the return value explanation is that the return is the number of structures which have nonzero revents fields. So if POLLERR is set, then there is at least 1 structure with nonzero revents.

Answer (score 4):

> If poll sets one of POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL in revents, does this mean that the poll function will return -1?

No.  If `poll()` sets any `revents` values then it will return `>0` to indicate that.  You then have to check the individual items to see which ones have `revents` values assigned.

> If not, when will poll return -1?

`poll()` returns `-1` only if `poll()` itself fails, not if any of the items being polled fail.